# Solve for variable in integral limit when using NIntegrate

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve for a variable which appears in the limits of an integral, rather like in the following;

```
Clear[f, a, x]
f[a_] := Integrate[x^2 + a x, {x, 0, a }]
f[Power[6, (3)^-1]]
NSolve[5 == f[a], a, Reals]
```

This works absolutely fine. But the integral I really care about is a mess, and so has, of course, no nice closed form. So I try the following;

```
Clear[f, a, x]
f[a_] := NIntegrate[x^2 + a x, {x, 0, a }]
f[Power[6, (3)^-1]]
NSolve[5 == f[a], a, Reals]
```

and this does not work. Instead I get `NIntegrate::nlim: x = a is not a valid limit of integration.` In both of these examples, the third line evaluates the function `f[a]` fine.
I also tried

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[x^2 + a x, {x, 0, a }]
```

which fails with `NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.`

I rather hoped the link below would answer my problem, but of course it refers to `Integrate`, not `NIntegrate`.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38012/compute-unknown-limit-from-known-integral-in-mathematica

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. When `a` is a symbol in `f[a_] := NIntegrate[x^2 + a x, {x, 0, a }]` you won't get the result.
2. Defining `f[a_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[...]` it can't work in `NSolve[5 == f[a], a, Reals]` since `a` is assumed to be a `Symbol` therein.

You can use

```
FindRoot[f[a] - 5, {a, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 1.81712}}
> ```

or you should define `f` this way:

```
f[a_] := Integrate[x^2 + a x, {x, 0, a}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `FindRoot[]`

```
Clear[f, a, x]
x0 = Power[6, (3)^-1];
f[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[x^2 + a x, {x, 0, a}]

(a /. FindRoot[f[a] == 5, {a, 1}]) == N@x0

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to do a scan of f[a] over a range of a's that you're interested in. You define an interpolation function to smooth out these values, then either FindRoot or NDSolve f[x] == 5.